# Why always hyperlinks to imgur.com?

Tags: discussion

Why do the puzzlers always link to imgur.com and never to another site for images?

How does steganography work? I don't understand how to solve the puzzles here. Can anybody help me?

Comment: On a side note, I'd like to mention that the "5 alphanumeric characters + optional 'png' implies i.stack.imgur image" association is quite local to Puzzling Stack Exchange. Having said that, I'm of the opinion that it would be helpful to newcomers if puzzlers could hint at imgur as well in their puzzles, but I admit that it's not always easy to do.

Comment: @Sp3000 Yawn. *So* tired of that gimmick by now.

Comment: These are two entirely separate questions, so please ask them separately

Answer (score 3):

> Why do the puzzlers always link to imgur.com and never to another site for images?

The standard resource for images on Stack Exchange is https://i.stack.imgur.com because this is the easiest to use on the SE platform. Whenever you're writing a post here, the "insert image" tool (accessible by clicking the icon at the top of the box where you're typing, or by pressing `Ctrl+G`) allows you to embed images into your post by uploading them to Stack.Imgur. This can be done for any images, whether they're stored on your computer or available on the web. You *can* also include images hosted using other services, and some people do, but the simplest thing to use is Imgur.

> How does steganography work?

Steganography works by hiding a secret message within what seems to be an ordinary, unsuspicious message. As mentioned in the [tag info page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/steganography/info), this can be done in many different ways. The easiest to understand is textual steganography. For a simple example, consider the following message:

*"Go only to Oliver; that honest engineer will aid you, supply things, and take in our nephew."*

On the surface it seems like it's saying one thing, but if you read only the first letter of each word, you get a quite different message: GO TO THE WAYSTATION.

This was a very basic example; steganography can get a lot more complicated. See [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42656/5373) for a more complex example of textual steganography.

> I don't understand how to solve the puzzles here. Can anybody help me?

It's a learning experience :-) Stick around here and watch the puzzles as they come in, and eventually you'll find one you can solve. And for each one you don't manage, you'll eventually see how it's solved by waiting to read the solution of whoever does manage it.